# d3 path: Why are square brackets used in .data([...])

Tags: d3.js

In d3 creating a path involves a sequence of method calls like this:

```
var path = svg.append("path")
        .data([points])
        .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
        .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
        .interpolate("cardinal-closed"));
```

This above is excerpted from the following:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868

Given that `points` is itself an array, why is it necessary to enclose points inside square brackets in the method invocation `.data([points])`?

I believe this inner square brackets requirement obtains in d3 v3 and v4.

Comment: I guess because it expects an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@davenewton's comment is close.  The simply answer is that `d3.line` expects an array.  By passing an array of arrays to `.data` `d3`'s data-binding will call `.attr` with the first array in that array of arrays.

Examine this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      d3.select('body')
        .append('div')
        .data([1,2,3])
        .attr('d', function(d, i){ 
          console.log(d, i); 
        });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is a strange use of the data-binding since it doesn't fulfill the `enter`, `update`, `exit` we usually use with data-binding (and that's why only the **first iteration** of binding get's called).

Finally, it should be noted that this code could be written as:

```
var path = svg.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed"));
```

Or even:

```
var path = svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed")(points));
```

Since:

```
.append("path")
.data([array])
.attr("d", line)
```

and

```
.append("path")
.datum(array)
.attr("d", line)
```

and

```
.append("path")
.attr("d", line(points))
```

are all equivalent.

Comment: Are you saying that when there are multiple div's (or whatever) in the body, that multiple paths can be generated, one for each div? And that's why an array of arrays is deployed?

Comment: @Argent, no, the way that is written `.append(...).data(...).attr(...)`, it'll only append and then iterate over the first argument in the array.  If you want to append multiple items, you'd need to follow the *conventional* use of de data-binding, `.selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...)`

Comment: @Argent, mbostock is really just using a clever hack on the `.data` call.  I'm not sure why he would write it like that (I wouldn't have).  I updated my answer with another way you could achieve the same results passing `points` to the line function.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Given that data() is looking for an array of items, if you want to pass an array, it must be the first item in a parent array. I agree that your use of the datum method (which I never saw before) is a cleaner way to achieve the same result.